# Should var statements be the first statements in JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, var

I'm currently using a JavaScript coding style based on Douglas Crockford's [Code Conventions for the JavaScript Programming Language](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), which means I declare all variables used in a function at the beginning of that function:

```
function drawTiles(tiles) {
    var x, y, tile;
    for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (y = 0; y < weight; y++) {
            tile = tiles[y][x];
            if (tile)
                drawTile(tile, x, y);
        }
}
```

This makes sense because variables in JavaScript are hoisted to the top of the function and function scoped anyway.

However, I get the impression that it is more popular to just declare them when first used, like this:

```
function drawTiles(tiles) {
    for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        for (var y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            var tile = tiles[y][x];
            if (tile)
                drawTile(tile, x, y);
        }
}
```

That's actually easier to work with IMO - you don't have to jump to the top of the current function whenever declaring a new variable. But it doesn't feel "right".

My question is: Which style is more popular among professional (and popular) JavaScript programmers? (I usually try to pick the most common code style used in the community)

I had a look at a few open source projects (Google's [Closure](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/), Facebook's [Phabricator](https://github.com/facebook/phabricator), [Facebook JS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk) and [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)) and it seems all (except jQuery) declare variables when first used most of the time. jQuery leans towards declaring them at the top of functions, but by no means consistent.

Comment: I think that for large functions with conditional statements it would actually be better to declare variables just before usage so you don't end up declaring and not using them (thus wasting resources).

Comment: take everything crockford says with a grain of salt. do whichever way feels best for you and other developers you work with.

Comment: FWIW, I declare them where I use them. Adhere to the conventions of the project you're developing for. If it's a new project or there are no conventions, create ones that suit the majorities programming style and stick to them.

Comment: Voting _not constructive_; it does not matter what is "popular" among "popular" JS programmers, however you might want to define "popular".

Comment: Bleh.. And I was just about to send a beautiful, constructive and helpful answer. It just took me too much time to beautify the formatting ;(

Comment: I'm sorry that you're not finding this question constructive, I do think the coding style for new projects matters - it won't be easy to change it later. Anyway, I did some further research and discovered code samples by John Resig (http://ejohn.org/blog/revised-javascript-dictionary-search/) and Brendan Eich (http://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/) who both declare vars when first used. So the only user of Crockford's style I could find is, well, Crockford. I'll adopt the second style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second style is popular because this is how you'd do it in most other languages, i.e. declaring the variable where it's used.

Future versions of ECMAScript will introduce block scope through the `let` keyword, which will probably change the way people write JS (tending more towards the 2nd style).

But other than that, if you keep your functions small, it really becomes a matter of taste.